# encoding JSON response using multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have an android project where I can already type a keyword in an editText field and search a MySQL database using php to retreive the proper JSON response.

Now I added two more spinners with text fields to make a more specific search in my database. Those two other fields are located in the same database but in diferent tables. ( Those two other tables simply contain id from 1 to 6 and strings for each id. The only value displayed in the main table from these two others is the id )

So now I'm sending three keywords ( keyword, keyword2 and keyword3 ) to the php . How do I make the apropriate search to test it in my browser ?
My attempt below displays null result. You can see I basically tried adding keyword2 and keyword3 and UNION to include two more SELECTs .

```
<?php

//error_reporting(E_ALL);
error_reporting(0);

require_once('db_config.php');

$conn = mysql_connect($db_server, $db_user, $db_password) or die(mysql_error());

$db=  mysql_select_db($db_database, $conn);

$keyword=$_GET["keyword"];
$keyword2=$_GET["keyword2"];
$keyword3=$_GET["keyword3"];

// $sql ="SELECT marca,imagempequena,marcatotal,actividade,datainicio FROM empresa WHERE marca LIKE '%$keyword%' and ficha LIKE '%1' ";

$sql = "(SELECT marca,imagempequena,marcatotal,actividade,datainicio FROM empresa WHERE marca LIKE '%$keyword%' and ficha LIKE '%1') 
           UNION
        (SELECT investimento FROM investimento WHERE investimento LIKE '%$keyword2%' ) 
           UNION
        (SELECT sector FROM sector WHERE sector LIKE '%$keyword3%' )";

header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');

$rs = mysql_query($sql,$conn);

$response["empresa"] = array();

while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($rs))

{
    $i=0;
    foreach($row as $key => $value)   
    {
        if (is_string($key))
        {
         $fields[mysql_field_name($rs,$i++)] = $value;
        }  
    }
    $json_result[] = $fields;
}
    // success
    $response["success"] = 1;

$response = json_encode($json_result);
echo($response);

?>
```

Comment: Those 2 relations to your "main" table could be drop down menus sending their ids. Since the ids are in your main table, it would make your query easier.

Comment: True but I can only send the strings to the php from android and not the id. and those strings are on the other 2 tables..

Comment: Drop downs on touchscreen would be easier to use for app users and as I suggested before the query would be easier and has a better performance. Since that is not possible for you, can you provide the table schemas and constraints, so it is possible to create a statement with joins? BTW the mysql functions are deprecated since PHP 5.5. I recommend mysqli or PDO.